# Why is this React Switch Case not working?

Tags: reactjs

First of all, I'm sorry for such a basic question, but I just started learning React from its official documentation.

[Initial state of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmdrZ.png)
I want to update the state of the topicTitle, topicContent and level when I click on the button 'Continue'. It should do so by calling the function `NextTopic` and incrementing `let level` in it. Then setting `this.state.level` to the value of the incremented variable `level`. After that the switch case should check the value of `this.state.level` and if it equals 1, update the state of topicName and topicContent.
[This is what my actually happens when my code runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rv2S.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    //default states
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            level: 0,
            topicTitle: 'Topic Name',
            topicContent: 'Content!!'
        }
    }

    render() {
        const NextTopic = (e) => {
            //increment level
            let level;
            level++;
            //set state of level to incremented let level
            this.setState({level: level});
            
            //check level of state and update topic name- and content state    
            switch(this.state.level) {
                case 1: 
                    return this.setState({topicTitle: 'new Topic Name', topicContent: 'new    Content!!'});
            }       
        }
        
        //Sidebar Component
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.topicTitle}</h1>
                <p>{this.state.topicContent}</p>
                <h2>Level: {this.state.level}</h2>
                <button id='next' onClick={NextTopic}>Continue</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: you are missing `level = this.state.level` just before `level++;`

Comment: yep and that is my error, thanks! =] @JoelHarkes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `level` to 0 in `NextTopic`. You can increment `level` by 1 directly in `setState`:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  level: prevState.level + 1
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

setState does not necessarily change the `level` property in your state by the time your switch-case is executed. React batches various setState calls and then calls it once per approximately 16.67ms. You can do two things -

1. Use the level variable you created inside the NextTopic method (also, how are you incrementing an undefined variable?

   let level = this.state.level
   level++
   this.setState({level: level})

   switch(level){
       case 1: // your code
   }
2. Wrap the switch-case inside a callback function to setState, which is called once the state is actually changed by react -

   let level = this.state.level
   level++
   this.setState({level}, () => {
     switch(this.state.level) {
       case 1: // your code
   })

Comment: additionaly you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973) for further understanding of when setState happens

Comment: Well, as you said in point 1, I haven't even defined that variable and that was my error. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @kugtas Thanks, I'll check it out =]