# continuous setState doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have below piece of code -

```
class Sum extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { a : 0 }
    }

    // let's call this ADD-1
    add = () => {
      this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 1 })
      this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 2 })
      this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 3 })
    } 

    render() {
      return (<div>
        <button onClick={this.add}> click me  </button>
        <div> sum  {this.state.a} </div>
      </div>)
    }
}
```

this renders on clicking the button

```
sum = 3
```

where as i was hoping that it will render `sum = 6` i.e  1 + 2 + 3

also, if I change my `add` method to something like to accommodate for `prevState` race condition-

```
  // let's call this ADD-2
  add = () => {
    this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 1 })
    this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 2 })
    this.setState(prevState => ({ a: prevState.a + 1 }))
    this.setState(prevState => ({ a: prevState.a + 4 }))
  }
```

it renders `sum = 7` whereas I was hoping for `sum = 8` i.e (1 + 2 + 1 + 4)

Now two questions come to my mind:-

1) Why do we see the results as the one mentioned above and not what I have expected?

2) Why don't I see the transition of addition in UI?
Say if we consider method tagged as `ADD-1`, I should be seeing something like `sum = 1` then `sum = 3` then `sum = 6`. Is it because of batching of updates but batching puts them in a queue of execution it doesn't override anything in my opinion.

Comment: setState is asynchronous all of those get called "essentially" at once. Meaning the last one is setting state to 0 + 3. setState method has a callback if you want to wait for it to update then call your other setState's. this.setState({value: value+1}, () => { this.setState({value: value + 2})}) 
https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State update maybe asynchronous. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41278385/6816939).

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48610973/6816939) by Dan abramov, it is stated that state updates within one event call will only produce a single re-render at the end of the event.

> no matter how many setState() calls in how many components you do
>   inside a React event handler, they will produce only a single
>   re-render at the end of the event.

And also batching happens only for state updates within a React event handler i.e batching does not happen inside AJAX calls

```
promise.then(() => {
  // We're not in an event handler, so these are flushed separately.
  this.setState({a: true}); // Re-renders with {a: true, b: false }
  this.setState({b: true}); // Re-renders with {a: true, b: true }
  this.props.setParentState(); // Re-renders the parent
});
```

But you could achieve what you want to by passing a callback to the `setState` method

```
add = () => {
      this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 1 },
        () => {
        this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 2 },
          () => {
          this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 3 })
        })
      })    
    }
```

The above will return sum = 6.

**When not to use callbacks in setState :**

> `PureComponent` and `shouldComponentUpdate` can be used to tune up a
>   component’s performance. They work by preventing lifecycle methods
>   from firing when props and state haven’t changed.
>
> The `setState` callback fires regardless of what `shouldComponentUpdate`
>   returns. So, the `setState` callback will fire, even when state hasn’t
>   changed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you pass a function to `setState` when your update is dependent on current state so it doesn't get overwritten by subsequent `setState`.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { a: 0 };

  add = () => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { a: previousState.a + 1 };
    });
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { a: previousState.a + 2 };
    });
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { a: previousState.a + 3 };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.add}> click me </button>
        <div> sum {this.state.a} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance."

From the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

state change can happen only through setState, but if you access and modify this.state before setState (this.state.a + 1) it won't reflect. so every time you access this.state.a it's getting 0 i.e initial value.

```
add = () => {
  this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 1 }) // 0 + 1
  this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 2 }) // 0 + 2
  this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 3 }) // 0 + 3
} 

this.setState((previousState) => { // change state using previousState} );
```

this is the way to have to update state