# How is React component's props updated asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

After digging around I thought I understood that a component's props cannot be updated by the component itself, although can be changed by the parent component.

However I found this one section in react docs:

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>   Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

So I am trying to interpret what this excerpt says with I have understood. If props is updated, then the update must come from parent component. If the update comes from a parent component, why is it possibly asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer given by zloctb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085726/why-is-setstate-in-reactjs-async-instead-of-sync)

```
// assuming this.state.count === 0
this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
// this.state.count === 1, not 3

Solution
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  count: prevState.count + props.increment
}));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I understand how setState() changes the value of this.state asynchronously, but I don't understand how the same applies to this.props since this.props cannot be changed by the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

> If props is updated, then the update must come from parent component.

That is correct.

> If the update comes from a parent component, why is it possibly asynchronous?

You can pass parent's `setState()` with props to a child and call it somewhere in child's code. And it still **may be** asynchronous. I came up with the following example:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  state = { containerState: 0 };
  render() {
    return (
      <Component
        containerState={this.state.containerState}
        setContainerState={this.setState.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And then, in child `Component`, you have code like this:

```
this.props.setContainerState({
  containerState: this.props.containerState + 1
});

// You want to use updated this.props.containerState here, but you can't,
// because parent's setState() MAY BE deferred
this.props.setState({ componentStateUpdatedWithObject: this.props.containerState });

// Now if you use the function instead, you can expect to get updated props
// as a second argument
this.props.setState((state, props) => ({ 
  componentStateUpdatedWithFunction: props.containerState 
}));
```

See the full code for my example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>

  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
    crossorigin
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
    crossorigin
  ></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    class Container extends React.Component {
      state = { containerState: 0 };

      render() {
        return (
          <Component
            containerState={this.state.containerState}
            setContainerState={this.setState.bind(this)}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    class Component extends React.Component {
      state = {
        componentStateUpdatedWithObject: [0, this.props.containerState],
        componentStateUpdatedWithFunction: [0, this.props.containerState]
      };

      log = title => {
        console.log(title);
        console.log("- containerState", this.props.containerState);
        console.log(
          "- componentStateUpdatedWithObject",
          this.state.componentStateUpdatedWithObject
        );
        console.log(
          "- componentStateUpdatedWithFunction",
          this.state.componentStateUpdatedWithFunction
        );
        console.log("==========");
      };

      update = () => {
        this.log("before update");
        this.props.setContainerState({
          containerState: this.props.containerState + 1
        });
        this.log("after setContainerState");
        this.setState({
          componentStateUpdatedWithObject: [
            this.state.componentStateUpdatedWithObject[0] + 1,
            this.props.containerState
          ]
        });
        this.log("after setState with object");
        this.setState((state, props) => ({
          componentStateUpdatedWithFunction: [
            state.componentStateUpdatedWithFunction[0] + 1,
            props.containerState
          ]
        }));
        this.log("after setState with function");
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        // setInterval(this.update, 2000);
      }

      render() {
        this.log("on render");
        console.log("---------------------------------------------");
        return (
          <div>
            <div>containerState: {this.props.containerState}</div>
            <div>
              componentStateUpdatedWithObject:{" "}
              {this.state.componentStateUpdatedWithObject.join(", ")}
            </div>
            <div>
              componentStateUpdatedWithFunction:{" "}
              {this.state.componentStateUpdatedWithFunction.join(", ")}
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.update}>UPDATE</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById("root"));
  </script>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Not all `setState()` calls are asynchronous. In my example if you uncomment `setInterval(this.update, 2000)` in the `componentDidMount`, you won't get the same behavior. This way `setState()` calls are synchronous.

See this link for explanation why this happens: [When and why are setState() calls batched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973)

In short, this is because

> Currently (React 16 and earlier), only updates inside React event handlers are batched by default. There is an unstable API to force batching outside of event handlers for rare cases when you need it.