# How do multiple calls to `setState` can be batched to one call?

Tags: reactjs

[From React getting started tutorial:](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.

How do multiple calls to `setState` can be batched to one call? Did they mean that multiple calls will be batched to multiple sync calls and one async call at the end?

I will love to see an example if it's possible.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates)