# react select onChange returning previous value instead of current

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to update the state of a `Parent` component *after* the user updates the value of a `Child` component's `select` element.

Whilst I've got it somewhat working, I've noticed that when I fire the `onChange` event on my `select`, it will always return the *previous* value instead of the value that has just been selected.

---

```
class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: {
            condition: "any"
        }};
    }

    update = data => {
        this.setState({ data: { 
            ...this.state.data, 
            ...data 
        }});
        
        // This gets called every time I change the value of my select element.
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Child
                condition={this.state.data.condition} 
                onUpdate={data => this.update(data)} />
        );
    }
}

class Child extends Component{
    updateParent = data => {
        this.props.onUpdate(data);
    }

    render(){
        const options = [
            ["any", "Any Condition"], 
            ["new", "Brand New"], 
            ["used", "Used"]
        ];

        return (
            <select 
                defaultValue={ props.selected } 
                onChange={({ target }) => this.updateParent({ condition: target.value })}>
                    { options.map(([id, name]) => (
                        <option key={id} value={id}>{ name }</option>
                    )}
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

In this example, if I select `used`, the console will return `any`. Then, if I select `new`, the console will return `used`.

Comment: Is it the console where you see the previous data , or even in the UI the previous data is displayed?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal just the console. when i select the new option, the select value does in fact change on the UI. but this does mean i'll run into problems later on when the ui _says_ it's doing one thing when it's actually doing another backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately) This question is asked several times/week. Please try to search before posting question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setState` operations are async in nature. So whenever a setState op is done, its not guaranteed that the updated value of state will be available just after the `setState`
statement

From React Doc

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
> performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
> should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

Now, if you want to use the new state value, you should store the value, in this case the `data`, in a variable, set your state, but use the variable to perform other operation inside the function, like calling API,etc.

Edit (As pointed out by @Grover):

`setState` also provides a second argument which is a callback that gets fired after the update operation takes place. One can get the updated state value in it and can use this to perform operations with the updated values.

```
this.setState({foo: 'bar'}, () => { 
    // actions
});
```

However, the React Doc suggests using componentDidUpdate instead of setState callback. This answer tries to explain it why: [What is the advantage of using componentDidUpdate over the setState callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501409/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-componentdidupdate-over-the-setstate-callback)