# Call functions synchronously in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I want to call an API in React after a function has been executed.

```
    const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    const [isValid, setValidation] = useState(true);
    const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useState('');

const validate = (callback) => {
        if (code == null || code.trim().length === 0) {
            setValidation(false);
            setValidationMessage(translate.signIn.codeErrorMessage);
            setVisible(true);
        } else if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.trim().length === 0) {
            setValidation(false);
            setValidationMessage(translate.signIn.phoneErrorMessage);
            setVisible(true);
        } 
        callback();
    }

    const authenticate = async () => {
        try {
            return await (authenticateUser.get('/abc', {
                params: {
                    code,
                    phoneNumber,
                }
            }));
        }
        catch (e) {
            setValidationMessage(translate.signIn.exceptionMessage);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    const validateUserCredentials = () => {
        if (isValid) {
            setActivitySpinner(true);
            authenticate().then(response => {
                setActivitySpinner(false);
                const responseData = response.data;
                console.log('responseData', responseData);
                if(responseData.status !== 200) {
                    setVisible(true);
                    setValidationMessage(responseData.message);
                }
                else if(responseData.status === 200) {
                    console.log('success');
                }
            });
        }
    }

  const onSubmit = () => {
        validate(validateUserCredentials);
    }
```

When I invoke 'onSubmit' function, even if the value of **isValid** is false. I can see the API is being called.
I want to call the function **validateUserCredentials** only after the function **validate** has done its task.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code must be working fine and you may be getting confused with the async nature of state update. Check this answer if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846824/react-select-onchange-returning-previous-value-instead-of-current/62846909#62846909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, for sure `validateUserCredentials` is called after `validate`, maybe you are confused because on `validateUserCredentials` you see that `isValid` stills true even if you setted as false.
Unfortunately with Hooks you cannot have callback as this.setState to have the certainty that `isValid` as been setted. What you can do is:

```
const validate = (callback) => {
    let isvalid_temp = isValid;
    if (code == null || code.trim().length === 0) {
        setValidation(false);
        isvalid_temp = false;
        setValidationMessage(translate.signIn.codeErrorMessage);
        setVisible(true);
    } else if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.trim().length === 0) {
        setValidation(false);
        isvalid_temp = false;
        setValidationMessage(translate.signIn.phoneErrorMessage);
        setVisible(true);
    } 
    callback(isvalid_temp);
}

const validateUserCredentials = (isvalid_temp) => {
    if (isvalid_temp) {
        setActivitySpinner(true);
        authenticate().then(response => {
            setActivitySpinner(false);
            const responseData = response.data;
            console.log('responseData', responseData);
            if(responseData.status !== 200) {
                setVisible(true);
                setValidationMessage(responseData.message);
            }
            else if(responseData.status === 200) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    }
}
```