# React batch updates for multiple setState() calls inside useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect

On this answer by Dan Abramov here on SO, I've found out the following:

[Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973)

> Currently (React 16 and earlier), **only updates inside React event handlers are batched by default.** There is an unstable API to force batching outside of event handlers for rare cases when you need it.

He also mentions that in this Github issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950

> In current release, **they will be batched together if you are inside a React event handler.** React batches all setStates done during a React event handler, and applies them just before exiting its own browser event handler.

But the fact is that **this snippet seems to prove** that updates for multiple `setState` calls inside a `useEffect()` **are batched.**

**QUESTION**

Does React also always batch updates for multiple `setState()` calls inside `useEffect` ? Where else does it do that ?

**NOTE:** According to his answers, on next major release (probably v17) React will batch everywhere by default.

**SNIPPET:** batch updates inside a `useEffect()` with multiple `setState()` calls

```js
function App() {

  console.log('Rendering app...');
  
  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState(0);
  const [booleanState, setBooleanState] = React.useState(false);
  
  console.log('myState: ' + myState);
  console.log('booleanState: ' + booleanState);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('Inside useEffect...');
    setMyState(1);
    setMyState((prevState) => prevState +1);
    setMyState(3);
    setMyState(4);
    setMyState(5);
    setBooleanState(true);
  },[]);

  return(
    <div>App - Check out my console!</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nice question. Here is additional info to complete @FranklinOcean answer.

**2021 update: upcoming changes in React 18**

Please see Dan Abramov update concerning this topic in React 18, which is the one that adds automatic batching: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

**Answer for current version of react, which is 17.0.2, and below, as of 2021.**

Based [on the following codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-brook-sgmsd):

---

**Batched `setStuff` calls:**

- Inline the component function block synchronously (I think it is equivalent to having an effect running before the other effects and without dependencies)
- In a `useEffect` block synchronously
- In a synthetic event handler synchronously (managed by react, such as `onClick={handlerFunction}`)

---

**Non batched calls that will trigger a re-render each time:**

- Any asynchronous code (promise/async function in any of the above use cases)
- Non synthetic event (event managed outside react lib)
- That includes XHR or other networks callbacks

---

I'll try re-run the sandbox with future versions of react to see how it goes!

Answer (score 4):

If state updates happen directly, React will batch your updates.

Batched:

```
export default () => { 
   const [a, setA] = React.useState(0); 
   const [b, setB] = React.useState(0);

   useEffect(() => {
    setA(1); setB(1);
   },[]);

   return (  
    <div> 
      <p>A: {a}</p> 
      <p>B: {b}</p> 
    </div> ); 
};
```

Clicking this button will re-render the component only once.

Non-Batched:

```
export default () => { 
  const [a, setA] = React.useState(0); 
  const [b, setB] = React.useState(0);

   useEffect(() => { 
    setTimeout(() => { setA(1); setB(1); }, 1000); }
   , []);

   return ( 
    <div> 
     <p>A: {a}</p> 
     <p>B: {b}</p> 
    </div> ); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just gonna drop in a "hack" that worked for me

```js
  const [dishes, dishesSet] = React.useState(state)
  const [isConnectedToDB, isConnectedToDBSet] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const databaseDishesRef = firebase.database().ref(process.env.FIREBASE_DISHES_REF)
    databaseDishesRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const value = snapshot.val()
      // isConnectedToDBSet(true) // this was not working
      dishesSet(() => {
        isConnectedToDBSet(true) // had to move it in here to batch the state updates

        return Object.entries(value).map(([, dish]) => dish)
      })
    })

    return () => {
      databaseDishesRef.off('value')
    }
  }, [])
```

The alternative would have been to wrote a `React.useEffect` for the `isConnectedToDB` and then trigger that on **every** dish update..