# What happens when setState is invoked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, setstate

I am learning React and having difficulty in understanding the flow of code that is happening.

Here is my code:It is a functional React component

```
function App() {
  const [x, setx] = useState(1);
  const [x1, setx1] = useState(1);
  const [x2, setx2] = useState(1);
  const [x3, setx3] = useState(1);
  const [x4, setx4] = useState(1);
  const [x5, setx5] = useState(1);

  console.log("out3");

  const bclick = () => {
    setx1(x1 + 1);
    setx2(x2 + 1);
    setx3(x3 + 1);
    setx4(x4 + 1);
    setx5(x5 + 1);
    setx(x + 1);
    console.log("out1");
    bclick2();
  };
  const bclick2 = () => {
    console.log("out2");
  };
  console.log("out4");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {console.log("in")}
      <button onClick={bclick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

output of console.log() after clicking on button:
out1
out2
out3
out4
in

---

Q> Upon clicking on button multiple different setStates are executed. Will they re-evaluate the component or the function chain(bclick and bclick2) complete executing and then App component is re-evaluated.
Based on my output I realise that function chain is executed first.
So is this how setState works?
Will flow of code complete first (irrespective of number of functions) and then functional component re-evaluated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates)

Comment: `out4` really should be `in0`. It happens during the rendering, just like `in`.

Comment: "*Will `setState` re-evaluate the component or will `bclick` complete executing before that?*" - IIRC, it depends on where `setState` is called from. If you call it from a `setTimeout` callback (or some other asnchronous thing that react doesn't know about), the component needs to be re-rendered synchronously. But if the call happens from an `onClick` via React itself, it will re-render only after all event handlers are executed.

Comment: @JaredSmith I don't think that's what the OP was asking

Comment: @Bergi I may have misunderstood

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885037/react-batch-updates-for-multiple-setstate-calls-inside-useeffect-hook

Comment: Thanks @Bergi and @Jared(the link did help in getting a better understanding of some related stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with React batching `setState` calls to optmize the number of renders. Usually you don't have to worry about that.

The `setState` call is `async`. React will decide when and how to apply multiple `setState` calls.

The handlers will always finish running before React re-renders. That's why you are seeing the `bclick2()` call running before any re-renders.

I feel that React will always go for batching multiple `setState` calls in a single re-render. But you can see that if you wrap multiple `setState` calls in `setTimeout`, React will re-render multiple times, because there's no way of it to know how long those timeouts will take to complete. You might be calling an API, for example.

```js
function App() {

  console.log('Rendering App...');

  const [x, setx] = React.useState(1);
  const [x1, setx1] = React.useState(1);
  const [x2, setx2] = React.useState(1);
  const [x3, setx3] = React.useState(1);
  const [x4, setx4] = React.useState(1);
  const [x5, setx5] = React.useState(1);

  const bclick = () => {
    console.clear();
    console.log("From bclick (batched: single render)");
    setx1(x1 + 1);
    setx2(x2 + 1);
    setx3(x3 + 1);
    setx4(x4 + 1);
    setx5(x5 + 1);
    setx(x + 1);
    console.log("Calling bclick2");
    bclick2();
  };

  const bclick2 = () => {
    console.log("From bclick2");
  };
  
  const notBatched = () => {
    console.clear();
    console.log('From notBatched (multiple renders)');
    setTimeout(() => setx1((prevState) => prevState+1),0);
    setTimeout(() => setx1((prevState) => prevState+1),0);
    setTimeout(() => setx1((prevState) => prevState+1),0);
  };
  
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={bclick}>Click (will batch)</button>
      <button onClick={notBatched}>Click (will not batch)</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

For example, if you are calling an API from a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);             // 1
  const data = await fetchAPI();  
  setData(data);                  // 2
  setIsLoading(false);            // 3
},[]);
```

In this case React wil run #1, and then, when the API call completes, it will run #2 and #3 separately (not batched). Not sure why it chooses to do it separately, because it would be safe to run them together, but I'm sure React has its own reasons for that. Probably the whole block that has been timeout'd because of the API call is flagged to `shouldNotBatch` somehow. I don't actually know what is the internal logic they use for this.

```js
const fetchAPI = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('DATA'),1500);
  });
}

const App = () => {
  console.log('Rendering App...');
  const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [data,setData] = React.useState(null);

  // I changed the `await` to `then` because SO snippets don't allow `await` in this case
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Running useEffect...');
    setIsLoading(true);             // 1
    fetchAPI().then((data) => {
      setData(data);                // 2
      setIsLoading(false);          // 3
    });;  
  },[]);

  return(
    <div>
      <div>isLoading:{JSON.stringify(isLoading)}</div>
      <div>data:{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

---

**React v18 (apr-2022)**

Apparently React v18 batches call from async handlers as well.

https://vogue.globo.com/celebridade/noticia/2022/04/bbb-portugal-bruna-gomes-e-pedida-em-namoro-por-bernardo-sousa.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.. Any good react course that you could recommend? I am a beginner and have decent experience with Javascript.

Comment: Start off with the docs on https://reactjs.org/ . Read it thoroughly. Then you can follow a tutorial for a ToDo list app, and then try to create your own from scratch. You can also watch some free online courses. But always refer to the documentation. Are you familiar with `npm` / `yarn` ? If not, take a course about those too.