# Why isn't the state from my hook updating properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a hook, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong conceptually, as it is unfortunately not working. I've written up a test example to recreate my problems - I'm unable to get `isCalculating` updates from my  Page. Many thanks in advance for your help.

**useTest.ts**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const TEST_LENGTH = 100 * 10000000
const TEST_CRITERIA = 99 * 10000000

const useTest = () => {
  const [isCalculating, setIsCalculating] = useState(false)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsCalculating(false)
  }, [result])
  const calculate = () => {
    setIsCalculating(true)
    for (let i = 0; i < TEST_LENGTH; i++) {
      if (i >= TEST_CRITERIA) {
        setResult(i)
        break
      }
    }
  }
  const reset = () => {
    setResult(0)
  }
  return { isCalculating, result, calculate, reset }
}

export default useTest
```

**Test.tsx**

```
import { Box, Button, Container, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { useTest } from '../helpers'

export default function Test() {
  const { isCalculating, result, calculate, reset } = useTest()
  return (
    <Container>
      <Box>
        <Text>Result: {result}</Text>
        {isCalculating ? <Text>is calculating...</Text> : null}
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            result === 0 ? calculate() : reset()
          }}>
          <Text>{result === 0 ? 'Calculate' : 'Reset'}</Text>
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

What I'm seeing is `isCalculating` updating in the hook only after the for loop calculation has finished, which for me is unexpected behavior. Any fixes to this?

**What I've tried**
Tried to mimic setState callback with useEffect in `useTest`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const TEST_LENGTH = 100 * 10000000
const TEST_CRITERIA = 99 * 10000000

const useTest = () => {
  const [isCalculating, setIsCalculating] = useState(false)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isCalculating) {
      for (let i = 0; i < TEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (i >= TEST_CRITERIA) {
          setResult(i)
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }, [isCalculating])
  const calculate = () => {
    setIsCalculating(true)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsCalculating(false)
  }, [result])
  const reset = () => {
    setResult(0)
  }
  return { isCalculating, result, calculate, reset }
}

export default useTest
```

Unfortunately (kind of expected) it still doesn't work.

CodeSandbox link: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-frost-x49p46?file=/package.json)
As you can see, the I've set up an alert and some text to show on screen when `isCalculating` is true, unfortunately they both don't show until the calculation has completed.

Comment: can you share your code with code sandbox?

Comment: @egemenakturk sure here's the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-frost-x49p46?file=/package.json

Comment: The loops are blocking the thread, you can wrap them in something like `setTimeout(() => {..}, 1)` [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-river-y87y4s?file=/src/useTest.js:431-563)

Comment: @Titus Oh, that's amazing. It totally works. Wondering if this is the only way though...seems kind of like a hack...Is this how other people do it?

Comment: the `useEffect` version (2nd version of hook) actually works if  you `console.log(isCalculating)` during render, just seems somehow painting part is still blocked by the loop. With first version of the `useTest` I guess I'd expect it to work the way it does.

Comment: I'm not sure how common that method is. You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#late_timeouts) a description of why it works.

Answer (score 1):

React automatically batches all the `setState` calls to one, in the `useEffect` to reduce the re-renders.

In your case, it batches all the `setState` calls at the end (waiting for for loop to end - blocking)

You can also have a look at [startTransition()](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#new-feature-automatic-batching) method which will do the same work in the different scenario.

Discussion: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

Similar: [React batch updates for multiple setState() calls inside useEffect hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885037/react-batch-updates-for-multiple-setstate-calls-inside-useeffect-hook)