# Why do I need to use setState callback to set state for second state item that relies on first item's setState finishing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this componentDidUpdate method, after performing setState to set quotes to what's returned from the fetch, I have to use the callback to perform setState a second time to set randomQuoteIndex to the result of calling randomQuoteIndex, which relies on `this.state.quotes.length`, i.e.:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nataliecardot/0ca0878d2f0c4210e2ed87a5f6947ec7/raw/1802a693d02ea086817e46a42413c0df4c077e3b/quotes.json')
      // Takes a JSON response string and parses it into JS object
      .then(response => response.json())
      // state is set to quotes: quotes due to destructuring
      // Using setState callback since setState is asynchronous and need to make sure quotes is loaded before setting the randomQuoteIndex state since it depends on it
      .then(quotes => this.setState({ quotes }, () => {
        this.setState({
          randomQuoteIndex: this.randomQuoteIndex(),
          isDoneFetching: true
        })
      }))
  }
```

Why doesn't the code below work? Based on the selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates), I'm under the impression that the second item in setState won't be applied until after state is set for the first item. If I try this, I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of undefined." (I read that setState is asynchronous and about when to use the callback but I'm having a hard time understanding what I read/how it applies in this case.)

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nataliecardot/0ca0878d2f0c4210e2ed87a5f6947ec7/raw/1802a693d02ea086817e46a42413c0df4c077e3b/quotes.json')
      // Takes a JSON response string and parses it into JS object
      .then(response => response.json())
      // Using setState callback since setState is asynchronous and need to make sure quotes is loaded before setting the randomQuoteIndex state since it depends on it
      .then(quotes => this.setState({
          quotes,
          randomQuoteIndex: this.randomQuoteIndex(),
          isDoneFetching: true
        }));
  }
```

Here's the full component code (the working version):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { random } from 'lodash';
import Button from './components/Button';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quotes: [],
      randomQuoteIndex: null,
      isDoneFetching: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nataliecardot/0ca0878d2f0c4210e2ed87a5f6947ec7/raw/1802a693d02ea086817e46a42413c0df4c077e3b/quotes.json')
      // Takes a JSON response string and parses it into JS object
      .then(response => response.json())
      // state is set to quotes: quotes due to destructuring
      // Using setState callback since setState is asynchronous and need to make sure quotes is loaded before setting the randomQuoteIndex state since it depends on it
      .then(quotes => this.setState({ quotes }, () => {
        this.setState({
          randomQuoteIndex: this.randomQuoteIndex(),
          isDoneFetching: true
        })
      }))
  }

  get randomQuote() {
    return this.state.quotes[this.state.randomQuoteIndex];
  }

  randomQuoteIndex() {
    return random(0, this.state.quotes.length - 1);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" id="quote-box">
        {this.state.isDoneFetching ? this.randomQuote.quote : 'Loading...'}
        <Button
          buttonDisplayName="Next"
          clickHandler={this.blah}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Well, the callback ensures that your previous state has been applied already. The question is, why should your `randomQuoteIndex` rely on a state property rather than retrieving an array as an argument, which would be a much more reusable concept (it doesn't even need to be inside the component anymore at that time)

Comment: where error is coming from? is it happening in `render()`?

Comment: I also don't really get why you would rely on a getter property to retrieve a quote, but then ask for the quote of the quote :)

Comment: My guess is that the culprit is the `this` reference in your callback. To verify, can you change `randomQuoteIndex: this.randomQuoteIndex()` to something else like `randomQuoteIndex: Date.now()` and see if that produces the same error?

Comment: Can you try using prevState on your quotes field, like in the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638938/updating-an-object-with-setstate-in-react ? If we want to keep fields on an object in setState, we need to either use prevState or a spread operator.

Comment: Arash -- the setState with the callback works. I'm just wondering why I can't have a single setState rather than one with a callback.

Comment: Icepickle -- yes since I'm not using a private variable using a getter function doesn't make that much sense (it was suggested in a tutorial since you don't have to bind it but I'll change it to a regular function). As for the randomQuoteIndex, not sure I get what you're saying but I have to use the length of the fetched quote list because the number of quotes in the list might change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that setState is asynchronous, it's a result of `randomQuoteIndex` being called before the state is set. This would be the case with or without asynchronous updating of state. Consider this slightly refactored version of `componentDidMount`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nataliecardot/0ca0878d2f0c4210e2ed87a5f6947ec7/raw/1802a693d02ea086817e46a42413c0df4c077e3b/quotes.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(quotes => {
        const newState = {
          randomQuoteIndex: this.randomQuoteIndex(),
          isDoneFetching: true,
          quotes
        }
        this.setState(newState)
      })
  }
```

This is functionally exactly the same as the version you posted in your question. Hopefully this highlights that `this.randomQuoteIndex()` is evaluated before `this.setState(newState)`, and because `setState` has not been called yet, there is no state, which `randomQuoteIndex` relies on. When calling `setState` the argument must be evaluated before it can be passed to `setState`, so synchronous or not, the update has not happed at the point that `randomQuoteIndex` is being called.

The easy way to fix this is to make `randomQuoteIndex` take the list of quotes as an argument rather than pulling it out of the component state. Rewritten, the pair of methods might look like:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nataliecardot/0ca0878d2f0c4210e2ed87a5f6947ec7/raw/1802a693d02ea086817e46a42413c0df4c077e3b/quotes.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(quotes => this.setState({
          quotes,
          randomQuoteIndex: this.randomQuoteIndex(quotes),
          isDoneFetching: true
        }));
  }

  randomQuoteIndex(quotes) {
    return random(0, quotes.length - 1);
  }
```

Which only requires that `setState` be called once, and (potentially) saves you a re-render.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, but I don't understand how -- in both this.randomQuoteIndex(quotes) and this.randomQuoteIndex(), the call relies on the state of quotes being set first. What am I missing? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you look at the refactored `this.randomQuoteIndex(quotes)` you'll see it doesn't actually use `this.state` at any point, `quotes` is getting passed in as an argument, and that's why it can be called before `setState` is done updating the component state.

Comment: I saw it didn't use `this.state`, but my confusion was that for the function to be invoked, it relies on the `quotes` state as an argument. But I see now it's just because everthing within the `componentDidMount` `setState` is applied at once (and not even in order), so `quotes` state is set at the same time as it's needed as an argument in `setState`'s `this.randomQuoteIndex(quotes)`. Anywho, do you know why `this.randomQuoteIndex()` inside `setState` would be called before `setState` (or could you suggest any docs that might explain further)?

Comment: `this.randomQuoteIndex()` is called before `setState` because of [eager evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation), that is in javascript arguments are always executed before a function or method is called on them. The output of `this.randomQuoteIndex()` is needed for `setState` to run, so it is evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't really think that React's authors intention about callback in `setState` was to use it to call next `setState`.
Why not to try something like @Icepickle mentioned:

```js
function randomQuoteIndex(quotes) {
  return random(0, quotes.length - 1);
}
...
...
  .then(quotes => {
    this.setState({
      quotes,
      randomQuoteIndex: randomQuoteIndex(quotes),
      isDoneFetching: true
    })
  }))
...
```

you update state only once => making sure about you have always just one render cycle