# does order of multiple setState() is respected in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

as in my question if i have different setState() calls does their order will be respected while executing them ? i know setState() is asynchronous , so if setState() number [1] for example which is heavy (got updated from a heavy code calculations) does it will execute and gave the result before or after a light setState() number [2] (got updated from a light code) ? i meant does setState() [2] will wait until setstate() [1] is finished ?

```
setState({imgfile:imgf});//[1]
setState({title:tit});//[2]
```

Comment: An experiment could have been done by self in this case. I don't think this is a valid question. But the answer I guess is NO. `Setstate` will not wait as it is asynchronous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates)

Answer (score 4):

If you want something to take action exactly after an update, you should use `this.setState`'s callback. By passing a second parameter to `this.setState` you can guarantee that your function will be executed after updating title.

```
this.setState({
  title: 'My title'
}, () => {
  this.setState({
    dogName: 'Rocky'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`setState` is asynchronous by design. When you call `setState` it isn't guaranteed to immediately update the state, it sends a request to update it. You don't want it synchronous and holding up the rendering of the UI if it's performing a complex change.

If you need to wait for your first `setState` to complete before doing something else then you can use a callback like so:

```
setState({imgfile:imgf}, () => 
{
   //do something
});
```

If your next operation is another state change then you should just batch them.

```
setState({imgfile:imgf, title: tit})
```

Answer (score 3):

> If I have different `setState()` calls does their order matter while executing them?

Basically, yes, it does. They are processed in the order in which they are queued up (and batched) during each render cycle.

> Will `setState()`[2] wait until `setstate()`[1] has finished?

No, all state updates are batched and process during react's reconciliation cycle.

1. In the case where each state update is independent, then the order in which they process doesn't really matter.
2. Sometimes, however, state updates *depend* on the previous state
   value, (i.e. incrementing counters); these are where you want to use
   functional state updates so if more than one update is queued then
   each subsequent update uses the result of the previous update.
3. In
   *some* other cases though, one state value *may* depend on another, different, state value.

Here's a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-bad-and-good-state-updates-2rtbk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) I use to help illustrate the second case.

For the third case there are a couple options. First is the class-based component's `setState` callback (functional components' `useState` hook does not have this), which is guaranteed to run *after* the state is updated. This, however, can lead to nesting issues. The second, and IMO, more correct way, is to use the component lifecycle functions (or hooks in functional components) to responded to specific state values updating and triggering other state updates to other state values.