# React event handler doesn't assign mode as expected, evaluates as null

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I have a page that looks like this:

[image]

When clicking the row's edit button, the component is supposed to set the selected entity to that row and put itself into "EDIT" mode.

However, when displaying a box in the upper right (component called toast here), the mode is evaluated to `null` on the very first click:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { Toast } from 'primereact/toast';

import 'primereact/resources/themes/luna-blue/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';

const modes =
{
    VIEW:   'VIEW',
    ADD:    'ADD',
    EDIT:   'EDIT',
    REMOVE: 'REMOVE'
}

class TestManager extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        let persons = [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "zipCode": "",
                "cityName": "",
                "streetName": "",
                "houseNbr": "",
                "firstName": "Ahmed",
                "lastName": "Al-Thiab",
                "gender": "MALE",
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "zipCode": "",
                "cityName": "",
                "streetName": "",
                "houseNbr": "",
                "firstName": "Stefan",
                "lastName": "Antalovics",
                "gender": "MALE",
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "zipCode": "",
                "cityName": "",
                "streetName": "",
                "houseNbr": "",
                "firstName": "Christian",
                "lastName": "Attina",
                "gender": "MALE",
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "zipCode": "",
                "cityName": "",
                "streetName": "",
                "houseNbr": "",
                "firstName": "Filmon",
                "lastName": "Berhane",
                "gender": "MALE",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "zipCode": "64895",
                "cityName": "Darmstadt",
                "streetName": "",
                "houseNbr": "",
                "firstName": "Johannes",
                "lastName": "Loczewski",
                "gender": "MALE",
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "zipCode": "22880",
                "cityName": "Wedel",
                "streetName": "Rosengarten",
                "houseNbr": "6",
                "firstName": "Karsten",
                "lastName": "Wutzke",
                "gender": "MALE",
            }
        ]
        
        this.state = {entities: persons,
                      selectedEntity: null,
                      mode: null};
        
        this.onRowEdit = this.onRowEdit.bind(this);
        this.onRowRemove = this.onRowRemove.bind(this);
        
        this.actions = this.actions.bind(this);
    }
    
    render()
    {
        var header = "Person Manager (" + this.state.entities.length + ")"

        return (
            <div style={{ maxWidth: 1000, marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto", marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10 }}>
                
                <Toast ref={(el) => this.toast = el} />
                
                <DataTable value={this.state.entities}
                           header={header}
                           dataKey="id"
                           selection={this.state.selectedEntity}
                           selectionMode="single"
                           sortField='lastName'
                           sortOrder={1}
                           resizableColumns
                           columnResizeMode="fit"
                           className="p-datatable-striped">
                    <Column field="id" header='ID' sortable style={{width:'7.5%'}} />
                    <Column field="gender" header='Sal.' body={this.salutation} sortable style={{width:'10%'}} />
                    <Column field='lastName' header='Last Name' sortable style={{width:'15%'}} />
                    <Column field='firstName' header='First Name' sortable style={{width:'15%'}} />
                    <Column field='streetName' header='Street' body={this.street} sortable style={{width:'20%'}} />
                    <Column field='zipCode' header='ZIP' sortable style={{width:'10%'}} />
                    <Column field='cityName' header='City' sortable style={{width:'10%'}} />
                    <Column field="actions" body={this.actions} style={{width:'12.5%'}} />
                </DataTable>
            </div>
        );
    }

    actions(rowData)
    {
        return (
            <>
                <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                    <Button icon="pi pi-pencil"
                            tooltip="Edit"
                            onClick={() => this.onRowEdit(rowData)}
                            className="p-button-sm p-button-raised p-button-rounded p-button-outlined" />
                    <Button icon="pi pi-trash"
                            tooltip="Remove"
                            className="p-button-sm p-button-raised p-button-rounded p-button-outlined"
                            onClick={() => this.onRowRemove(rowData)}
                            style={{marginLeft: 5}} />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }

    onRowEdit(rowData)
    {
        this.setState({selectedEntity: rowData});
        this.setState({mode: modes.EDIT});

        console.log("Last name: " + rowData.lastName);
        console.log("Mode: " + this.state.mode);

        this.toast.show({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Editing Person', detail: 'Name: ' + rowData.lastName + ", " + this.state.mode, life: 3000 });
    }

    onRowRemove(rowData)
    {
        this.setState({selectedEntity: rowData});
        this.setState({mode: modes.REMOVE});

        this.toast.show({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Removing Person', detail: 'Name: ' + rowData.lastName + ", " + this.state.mode, life: 3000 });
    }

    salutation(rowData)
    {
        var gender = rowData['gender'];

        if ( gender )
        {
            switch( gender )
            {
                case "MALE":
                    return "Mr";
                
                case "FEMALE":
                    return "Mrs";
                
                default:
                    return "Error";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    street(rowData)
    {
        var streetName = rowData['streetName'];
        var houseNumber = rowData['houseNbr'];

        return houseNumber ? streetName + " " + houseNumber : streetName;
    }
}

export default TestManager;
```

**QUESTION**:

What's wrong here?

According to this

[Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973)

there shouldn't be any problems with the method callback, a.k.a. as event handler, updating the mode

```
onRowEdit(rowData)
{
    this.setState({selectedEntity: rowData});
    this.setState({mode: modes.EDIT});

    console.log("Last name: " + rowData.lastName);
    console.log("Mode: " + this.state.mode);

    this.toast.show({ severity: 'info', summary: 'Editing Person', detail: 'Name: ' + rowData.lastName + ", " + this.state.mode, life: 3000 });
}
```

`this.state.mode` is always `null` on the very first click. On subsequent clicks, no matter which row, the correct mode is being shown.

Why?

How do I fix this?

BTW: `this.state.selectedEntity` on the line using toast is `null` as well.

I'm having trouble understanding this. -> self-learner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state updates won't be (necessarily) reflected in `this.state` until the next render.

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback

You already know the mode, so you can either pass `modes.EDIT` instead of `this.state.mode`:

```
this.toast.show({ detail: "..." + modes.EDIT, life: 3000 });
```

or use the callback form of setState which ensures that state has updated before calling the subsequent toast code:

```
this.setState({mode: modes.EDIT}, () => this.toast.show( ... ))
```

Note: it's possible that your `console.log` call will show the updated value because console.log runs asynchronously. (Between the time you call it and the time it appears in the console the state may have changed.)

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is async. You can't expect your state to have changed yet.

Try this:

```js
this.setState({mode: modes.EDIT}, () => {
  console.log("Mode: " + this.state.mode);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a fair question but setState is async. So either use callback function inside it or use Promise to execute some setState after another setState

`this.setState( (mode) =>  mode : modes.EDIT)`

or

`Promise.all(#First Async).then(#Second Async)`