# React: update hook variable immediately (to be used by another function for adding/removing event listeners)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There is a React component I'd like to refactor to a functional component using hooks. The function looks like this:

```
const T = () => {
    const [idx, setIdx] = React.useState<number>(0);
    
    ...

    const func1 = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, c: number) => {
        setIdx(c);
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", func2);
    }
    
    const func2 = (e: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log(idx);
    }
}
```

`func1` is something called on mouse down.
`func2` is something that gets called by an event listener while the mouse is dragged. The whole function is quite complex so I'm hoping for minimal restructuring.

How can I get `func2` to get the new version of `idx`?

*Edit:
For some reasons, this has been marked as a duplicate of [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately) The accepted solution from the link (`useEffect`) does not work in my example for removing event listeners. In my post, the first solution of the accepted answer works (the second part doesn't).

Comment: Why are you adding the `mousemove` event listener in the `func1`, shouldn't it be in a `useEffect`. I upvoted @Ismail_Aj's answer, it seems the most reasonable here given that state updates are not instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `func2` is defined when the component is loaded/updated, and since state updates are asynchronous, then when you're adding the event listener, it sets the currently defined `func2` with the original `idx` as the callback.

What you can do is to wrap func2 in a function that takes `idx` as a parameter and returns a function that can then act as the callback.

Then you add the listener in `setState`'s callback to use the new state value right away.

```js
const { useState } = React

const T = () => {
    const [idx, setIdx] = useState(0);
    
    const func1 = (e, c) => {
        setIdx(prev => {
          let newIdx = 1; // 1 instead of c for the example
          window.addEventListener("mousemove", func2(newIdx)); // call outer func2 with new state
          return newIdx // set new state
        });
    }
    
    const func2 = idx => (e) => {
        console.log(idx);
    }
    
    return <div id="drag-me" onClick={func1}>Click Here</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
<T />,
window.root
)
```

```css
#drag-me{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can also use `useEffect` to add the event listener, but it'll run each time `idx` is set, including when the component first mounts. You can use states to control this. For example, I used a state that represents `func1` being called.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const T = () => {
    const [idx, setIdx] = useState(0);
    const [funcCalled, setFuncCalled] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(()=> {
      if(!funcCalled) return
      const func2 = e => console.log(idx);
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', func2);
      return () =>{
        if (!funcCalled) return
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', func2)
      } // Cleanup after component unmounts
    },[funcCalled]) 
    
    const func1 = (e, c) => {
        setIdx(1) // 1 instead of c for the example
        setFuncCalled(true) // React respects state update order
    }
    
    
    return <div id="drag-me" onClick={func1}>Click Here</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
<T />,
window.root
)
```

```css
#drag-me{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Don't worry about the order of state updates, react will update `idx` first becfore updating `funcCalled`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates)

Comment: The first solution is very neat thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want `idx` to be updated immediately don't you should look for a solution combining `useEffect` and `useRef` hooks, due to the fact that `useState` works asynchronously it waits until it gathers all state updates then perform them all for performance.

```js
const refIdx = useRef<number>(0);
   const func1 = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>, c: number) => {
        refIdx.current = c;
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", func2);
    }
useEffect(() => {
 // perform the action you want to trigger on idxChange here
}, [refIdx.current]}
```