# React.js -- Table not redrawn when data is filtered

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, drawing, use-effect

I have a table in Next.js that, despite inputting the text into a text field, isn't being redrawn.  When redrawn, the table should return a single result, but it is currently only updating the top row to make the search result visible.

Here is my `useEffect` and where my state is declared:

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

//Get data from database
useEffect(() => {
  if (!checked) {
    setChecked(true);
    fetchData();
  }
  let data: any =
    inputText && inputText !== ""
      ? rows.filter(
          (item: any) =>
            item?.product_id?.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputText.toLowerCase()) !==
            -1
        )
      : rows;
  setFilteredData(data);
  console.log("results: ", data, inputText);
}, [checked, inputText]);
```

Here is my `fetchData()` function:

```
const fetchData: any = async () => {
  const response: any = await axios.get(`/api/layer_data`);
  setChecked(true);
  // setRows.checked(false);
  let dataRows: any[] = response.data;
  dataRows.map((dataRow: any) => (dataRow.isSelected = false));
  console.log("response: ", response.data);
  setRows(dataRows);
  setFilteredData(dataRows as any);
};
```

Here is where I draw the table:

```
<>
  {filteredData
    ?.sort(getComparator(order, orderBy))
    .map((row: any, index: any) => {
      const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.product_id);
      const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

      return (
        <StyledTableRow
          hover
          onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.product_id)}
          role="checkbox"
          aria-checked={isItemSelected}
          tabIndex={-1}
          key={row.product_id}
          selected={isItemSelected}
        >
          <StyledTableCell padding="checkbox">
            <Checkbox
              color="primary"
              checked={row.isSelected}
              inputProps={{
                "aria-labelledby": labelId,
              }}
              onChange={handleCheckbox}
              value={index}
            />
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">
            <input
              type="number"
              min="0"
              required
              defaultValue="0"
              onChange={(e) => handleInput(e, index)}
            />
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.sku_id}</StyledTableCell>

          <StyledTableCell
            component="th"
            id={labelId}
            scope="row"
            padding="none"
            align="right"
          >
            {row.product_id}
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.in_stock}</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.bin}</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.units_per_layer}</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.description}</StyledTableCell>
        </StyledTableRow>
      );
    })}
</>;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the async function `fetchData` is not being awaited, so the logic starting from `let data: any = ...` would probably acting strangely because some of them depend on the states updated in `fetchData`, but `fetchData` has not even started yet.

Also, since [`setState` is not always synchronous](https://ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately), the states are not guaranteed to be the newest/latest after `setState` is called until the next re-render. So even if you `await fetchData()`, your code might still not run in the way you expect it to be.

Use `useEffect` one after another to make sure each part of the logic is executed at the right time can fix your problem, but that is going to make the component so hard to read and maintain, which is apparently not a good choice.

If [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973) is enabled & used in the version of React you're using, the following code would probably work if we want to keep most of the logic the same: (I'm mentioning batching here because you `setChecked` and `setRows` in `fetchData`, but only `checked` is in the dependency list of `useEffect`.)

```js
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]); // <- I assume you have something like this in your component.
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

const fetchData = async (): any[] => {
  const response: any = await axios.get(`/api/layer_data`);
  setChecked(true);
  // setRows.checked(false);
  let dataRows: any[] = response.data;
  dataRows.map((dataRow: any) => (dataRow.isSelected = false));
  console.log("response: ", response.data);
  setRows(dataRows);
  setFilteredData(dataRows as any);
  // [ADDED]: We return dataRows in this function.
  return dataRows;
};

useEffect(() => {
  //Get data from database
  // [ADDED]: create an async function here because we have to use await in an effect.
  const computeFilteredData = async () => {
    let fetchedRows: any[]
    if (!checked) {
      setChecked(true);
      fetchedRows = await fetchData();
    } else {
      fetchedRows = rows;
    }
    let data: any =
      inputText && inputText !== ""
        ? fetchedRows.filter(
            (item: any) =>
      item?.product_id?.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputText.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          )
      : fetchedRows;
    setFilteredData(data);
    console.log("results: ", data, inputText);
  };
  computeFilteredData();
}, [checked, inputText]);
```

However, from the code you provided, `filteredData` looks more like a computed property based on `rows` and `inputText`. Therefore, it probably makes more sense to use `useMemo` in this case, so that we don't have to worry about manually updating `filteredData` every time `rows` or `inputText` changes; but I'm not sure if that fully suits your case:

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";

const filteredData: any[] = useMemo(() => {
  if (inputText && inputText !== "") {
    return rows.filter(
      (item: any) =>
        item?.product_id?.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputText.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    );
  } else {
    return rows;
  }
}, [rows, inputText]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I apologize for taking so long to get back to you.  I have tried both of the solutions you provided, and unfortunately, it looks like the table is still not redrawn as I described in the initial question.  The code I have provided successfully returns the correct result, but the table still is not redrawn, so ONLY that result is returned.  Instead, all rows are returned with the correct result at the top.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe I didn't correctly understand the issue you described. Could you please provide a sandbox (StackBlitz, CodeSandbox, etc) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Could you see `react-query` as a potential fix to this?  If so, why/why not?  I ask because I'm not sure I am using `useEffect` correctly.