# Best way to ensure multiple states are updated and call a function once all states updated [React Functional component]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my use case there are some controlled input components that stores data in states. When I change one of the dropdown input, it changes 3 more states and triggers an API call. How can I ensure that the 3 states are updated before making the API call ? I am using react functional component.

Comment: why do you want to wait before all 3 states are updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

If you're using React 18 and you call those 3 `setState(...)` within the same function, those states are guaranteed to be updated in the next re-render thanks to [automatic batching](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#whats-new-in-react-18).

So in this case you can just use an `useEffect` on any of these 3 states, and call the API in that effect. Check [this sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fume9g?file=src%2FApp.js) for a simple example.

**Option 2**

For people using React 17 or earlier, you still got auto batching, but **only inside React event handlers** (please refer to [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973)). If you're updating states outside React event handlers, the easiest way is, instead of `useState` three times, you just put those states in a single state in the first place to make sure they will be updated at the same time, because they are in the same state.

For example:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  state0: 0,
  state1: 'a',
  state2: true,
})

useEffect(() => {
  // Call API here
}, [state])
```