# is the DOM updated after each change + render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to fully understand the relations among DOM reconciliation, virtual DOM, component rendering and effect hook. I'm using the following code, which returns a status of "three". But are the intermediate statuses "one" and "two" always printed on the DOM, even for a blinky fraction of a second?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("zero");

  const handleChangeStatus = () => {
    setStatus("one");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "one") {
      setStatus("two");
    }
  }, [status]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "two") {
      setStatus("three");
    }
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id={status}>{status}</div>
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleChangeStatus}>Change statuses</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

once clicked,

Comment: Open chrome dev tools, find the div node in inspector, right-click on this div element and enable Break on Subtree Modifications. You will be able to see "one" "two" "three" clicking "continue" button

Comment: actually I've tried it, but it's quite a bit empirical! Are we sure it is a deterministic rule? Actually the central point of the question could be: is useEffect with a variable watch called always _after_ the DOM has been updated, and hence a render has been called + virtual dom updated + DOM reconciliated?

Comment: You should check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates/48610973#48610973)

Comment: Based on the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), "React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.". The word "may" makes me think this is not a deterministic rule. But see @Bertuz 's comment

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom Yes, but setState is async operation, it does not updates the value immediatelly. So state changed from "zero" to "one" with click - all 3 useEffects executed, only one of them changed the value to next but "next" will appear on next render only, on next execution of the component function.

Comment: @SergeySosunov It seems to be a common misconception/misunderstanding that "setState is async operation". It's not. The `setState` function is a completely synchronous function. It's the enqueued state update that asynchronously processed by React later. Updating React states is the asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, the `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle after content has been flushed to the DOM. Each `useEffect` hook runs each render cycle in the order they are declared. Each `useEffect` hook enqueues a state update on a different render cycle based on the dependency's value in the effect callback.

> But are the intermediate statuses "one" and "two" always printed on
> the DOM, even for a blinky fraction of a second?

Yes, they are. Each state update is enqueued in a different render cycle, so each update will be processed and the reconciled diff flushed to the DOM and rendered. The React framework aims for about a 60fps refresh rate, or, about 17ms per render cycle. The basic math: 1s/60render * 1000ms/1s = 1000ms/60render = 16.6667ms/render. 17ms is nearly imperceptible I dare say.

If you take this into account and multiply by the 3 triggered state updates, we're talking about around 50ms for just React doing the work. That's *still* nearly imperceptible. For reference, it seems the [average time for a human to blink is between 100-150ms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinking).

You can also very easily test this out for yourself with a couple extra `useEffect` hooks logging out the state updates and render cycles. Take note of the timestamps in the log output.

```js
function App() {
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState("zero");

  const handleChangeStatus = () => {
    setStatus("one");
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "one") {
      setStatus("two");
    }
  }, [status]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "two") {
      setStatus("three");
    }
  }, [status]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Status updated", status);
  }, [status]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component rendered")
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <div id={status}>{status}</div>
      <button onClick={handleChangeStatus}>Change statuses</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```