# what's the order of consecutive useState setters inside useEffect or handler in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, setter

is there any promise about order of useState setters,
lets say my code looks like this:

```
const [one,setOne]=useState(0)
const [two,setTwo]=useState(0)
```

and lets say theres a handler or a useEffect with the 2 consecutive lines:

```
setOne(1)
setTwo(1)
```

is there a guarantee on which setter runs first? I'm asking since its not the same as asynchronous function followed by synchronous function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does React keep the order for state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563650/does-react-keep-the-order-for-state-updates)

Comment: React state update when component re render. For your question both state will be updated when component re render

Answer (score 1):

React does batching of all state updates at once so order does not really matter...if there are consecutive state updates then React will update in a single render.
useEffect run in the order in which they are defined.