# Why onDoubleClick event is not working in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Task( {task , deleteTask , onToggle}) {
    
return (
        <div className='task' onDoubleClick={()=>onToggle(task.id)}>

          <h3>{task.text} 

            <FaTimes style= {{color:'red' , cursor:'pointer'}}

            onClick={()=>deleteTask(task.id)}/>

          </h3>

            <p>{task.day}</p>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Task
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onClick works but onDoubleClick is ignored on React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777826/onclick-works-but-ondoubleclick-is-ignored-on-react-component)

Comment: @MhkAsif that was for a single DOM element. here, the events are on different elements. Check this one out, [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-morning-trbie). this one works

Comment: yap, I also could make it works, here [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-dawn-uqz9z?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: can you put your code in codesandbox as it's working on my app

Comment: onDoubleClick={()=>console.log("double clicked")}
check if it is giving result in console or not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I suspected the double click is not working properly when the development tool is opened. So I changed console.log() into alert() and closed the inspector. It works for me.