# onDoubleClick is not working on react to call a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ondoubleclick

I'm following this React tutorial here: https://ibaslogic.com/how-to-edit-todos-items-in-react/ to build a simple TO DO app.

I've also reviewed [Why onDoubleClick event is not working in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408945/why-ondoubleclick-event-is-not-working-in-react-js) but there's no `onclick` event to worry about in my example.

My `onDoubleClick` event should call a function `handleEditing` but nothing happens when I double click a list item.

I'm unsure of why it does not work (the web browser does not seem to register a double click event.

Below is my example:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./TodoItem.module.css";

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  state = {
    editing: false,
  };

  handleEditing = () => {
      console.log("doubleClick")
    this.setState({
      editing: true,
    });
  };

  render() {

    const completedStyle = {
      fontStyle: "italic",
      color: "#595959",
      opacity: 0.4,
      textDecoration: "line-through",
    };
    
    const { completed, id, title } = this.props.todo;
    
    let viewMode = {}
let editMode = {}

if (this.state.editing) {
  viewMode.display = "none"
} else {
  editMode.display = "none"
}
    
    return (
      <li className={styles.item}>
        <div onDoubleClick={this.handleEditing} style={viewMode}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            className={styles.checkbox}
            checked={completed}
            onChange={() => this.props.handleChangeProps(id)}
          />
          <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteTodoProps(id)}>Delete</button>
          <span style={completed ? completedStyle : null}>{title}</span>
        
        </div>
        <input type="text" style={editMode} className={styles.textInput} />
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

I don't think this is relevant, but here is my css:

```
.item {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 17px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  }
  
  .checkbox {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
  
  .item button {
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #f1f3f4;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
  }


  .textInput {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  }
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Could you post your code on codesandbox and post it here?

Answer (score 3):

onDoubleClick works when your dev tool is not opened

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer:**

As found out in the comments, the problem was a combination of OS and Browser. Windows / Chrome in this example.

**Old answer:**

I haven't read into much detail, but the first difference I can spot is that in your code the handleEditing is not bound. Which should not prevent the output of your console.log. Does it appear?

```
onDoubleClick={this.handleEditing.bind(this)}
```

Hope this helps in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your response @csenk -- it unfortunately does not seem to help as the function is not being called

Comment: Hey @KatieMelosto, no problem. I've quickly tried your code in: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-dewdney-lfct8?file=/src/App.js and it seemed to work for me. Using it in Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: `handleEditing` is an arrow function, so you don't need to bind `this`.

Comment: Indeed :) The details do matter :D

Comment: Hi @csenk... I actually switched over to internet explorer on windows and it works now!

Comment: It did not work on Chrome on windows for some reason

Comment: Ok, so the code itself was fine at least :)

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for your help. Weirdly it seems to only work when the "inspect elements" is not on. When it's on, I can't get the double click to work....